# x-www-form-urlencoded parse by Django

Tags: android, python, json, django

I create android API using django framework.I send post request to server in x-www-form-urlencoded form but i dont know how to parse by django framework.so how to parse it.

i am using postman to test api and using `**post method => body => x-www-form-urlencoded**` and send data is

```
name     abc 
email    abc@gmail.com  
contact  1234567890
```

and this is **view.py** to get data

```
def user_otp_authetication(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        objs = request.body.decode('utf-8')
        print obj

        return json_response({
            'success':'true'
        })
```

print value

```
name=abc&email=abc%40gmail.com&contact=1234567890
```

how to parse this data for use.I also use json.loads() but it is not json so its through error message.

Comment: If despite the accepted answer you still need to parse the query params (for example because they are _not_ coming from the request) then see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47179840/191246

Answer (score 9):

`Django` is already parsing the `POST` data as a `dict-like` object in `request.POST`.

For example you can get the `name` using: `request.POST.get('name')`.
You can read more about `Django's` `request` object and the so-called `QueryDict` objects [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/).