# How to parse URL encoded data recieved via POST

Tags: python, json, django

I'm writing a django webhook for a service that send data via `POST` that is URL encoded. Example `POST` show below:

```
POST id=a5f3ca18-2935-11e7-ad46-08002720e7b4
 &originator=1123456789
 &recipient=1987654321
 &subject=MMS+reply
 &body=View+our+logo
 &mediaUrls[0]=https://storage.googleapis.com/mms-assets/20170424/a0b40b77-30f8-4603-adf1-00be9321885b-messagebird.png
 &mediaContentTypes[0]=image/png
 &createdDatetime=2017-04-24T20:15:30+00:00
```

I understand how to parse `json` but I haven't encountered this format before. There doesn't appear to be any useful tutorials for how to handle this via `POST`. I'm stuck at this point so help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a query string, check this question out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912843/python-how-to-convert-a-query-string-to-json-string

Answer (score 24):

Python 2:

```
>>> from urlparse import parse_qs
>>> parse_qs('foo=spam&bar=answer&bar=42')
{'foo': ['spam'], 'bar': ['answer', '42']}
```

Python 3:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import parse_qs
>>> parse_qs('foo=spam&bar=answer&bar=42')
{'foo': ['spam'], 'bar': ['answer', '42']}
```

Both python 2/3:

```
>>> from six.moves.urllib.parse import parse_qs
```

**UPD**

There is also `parse_qsl` function that returns a list of two-items tuples, like

```
>>> parse_qsl('foo=spam&bar=answer&bar=42')
[('foo', 'spam'), ('bar', 'answer'), ('bar', '42')]
```

It is very suitable to passing such list to `dict()` constructor, meaning that you got a dict with only one value per name. Note that the last name/value pair takes precedence over early occurrences of same name (see [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) in library reference).

Comment: This solution is not suitable for widely accepted nested data. For example `parse_qsl('foo=spam&bar=answer&bar[1]=42'` will result in `[('foo', 'spam'), ('bar', 'answer'), ('bar[1]', '42')]`

Comment: This form is not standard by any means.