# send forward slash "\" in http post

Tags: html, http, http-post, webserver

hello i am using a very basic html form :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The form method="post" attribute</h1>

<form action="http://123.123.123.123" method="post" target="_blank">
<label for="key1">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="key1" name="key1"><br><br>
  <label for="key2">Last name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="key2" name="key2"><br><br>

    <label for="key3">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="key3" name="key3"><br><br>
  <label for="key4">Last name:</label>
 <input type="text" id="key4" name="key4"><br><br>



  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

i am using this form to receive http post request to my python http server, the problem is ,in the last field , i need the the `1\` in the request that i receive on the server to save it into a variable and use it in os.path.join, but when i try to send request containing "\" i receive : `1%5C` instead of, how can i send \ 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

`%5C` **is** a `\` in the standard form encoding.

You need to decode it on the server. You could [do it manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44993390/how-to-parse-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-recieved-via-post), but you should be using an HTTP server library that does it for you automatically. e.g. [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/).

Comment: i am using simple http server to receive the request , so is there any way to decode it in one or two lines of code ?