# How do I send a pdf file from Groovy controller to be processed by my Flask end point?

Tags: java, python, flask, groovy, gsp

I am trying to send a pdf file from my Groovy controller to be processed by my Flask end point. I want to encode it to b64 format and decode and access the file at my Flask end point. The pdf file is coming from my gsp file. Any suggestions on how I could do the same?

Groovy controller:

```
def extractDocument(){
        def file = params.filename
        if (file instanceof MultipartFile && file != null){
            byte[] encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(file.getBytes());
            println(encoded)

            try{
                //request_generator(encoded)
                HttpURLConnection post = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://127.0.0.1:5000/uploadDoc").openConnection();
                post.setRequestMethod("POST")
                post.setDoOutput(true)
                post.setRequestProperty("Authorisation", "basic")
                //OutputStream
                post.getOutputStream().write(encoded)
                def postRC = post.getResponseCode()
                println(postRC)

                if(postRC == 200) {
                    println(post.getInputStream().getText());
                }
                else{
                    println("Not connect")
                }
```

GSP:

```
<g:uploadForm url= "[controller:'Document', action:'extractDocument']" method="post">
    <input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</g:uploadForm>
```

Flask app:

```
@app.route('/uploadDoc', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def upload_file():
    print('Hello')
    file1 = request.data
    file2 = base64.b64decode(file1)
    print(file2)
    print(file1)
    print(request.method)
```

When trying to send a file I am getting the following results on my Flask app:
Hello
b''
b''
POST

Comment: You do not show a single line of your Flask code. A POST endpoint is a standard Flask thing shown in almost all Flask tutorials. Please try at least.

Comment: Please check out the edited question, I have added my Flask app code and the result that I am getting. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

This will be a tough question to answer as I am not sure how many developers are out there, who speak both Python and Groovy, and maybe use both utilized frameworks.

So, instead of a solution in code, I offer some general debugging techniques which I use when I have such problems.

**limit the problem scope**

Basically, the problem could be in at least three areas.

- the Groovy code
- the Python code
- the network transportation

I'd try to narrow down the problem.

Depending on your knowledge and preferences...

**the Groovy code**

Unfortunately, I am no Groovy developer.

You could try to write tests for your code, so you can be sure it is doing what you expect.

Also, I'd probably refactor the code. Your `extractDocument` is not only extracting, but doing several things, including converting and sending. This makes it hard to test.

You could read on `Single Responsibility Principle` and `Dependency Injection`.

**the Python code**

As above, try to write tests.

Or start a debugger. This can be easily done with inserting `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` on just the line, before it is getting interesting. e.g. after your `print(hello)`.

**the network**

You could also send some input via `curl` directly to your endpoint.

This is maybe not the answer you expected, but when trying to do so, you can find out the problem yourself and also help yourself in future.

Comment: Glad you liked my answer. I'd appreciate if you can give my answer an arrow up, even when it is not the perfect solution :-) Good luck! And tell us how it worked out! If it turns out that the problem is within the Python code or in Flask, I am able to help.

Comment: Hi! Just a follow up question.  Flask:
file1 = request.get_data()
print(request.content_length)  --> 39716
print(chardet.detect(file1))  --> {'encoding': 'ascii', 'confidence': 1.0, 'language': ''}
print(request.content_type)  --> application/x-www-form-urlencoded

I am not able to understand how to decode and access the original file. Please let me know if you need more details to understand the problem.

Comment: I hope this answer helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44993390/how-to-parse-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-recieved-via-post

Comment: Hi! Another update: I am able to decode my file on the flask end point but I am saving it in a temporary file.
file1 = request.get_data()
file2 = base64.b64decode(file1)
with open (UPLOAD_FOLDER+'temp.pdf', 'wb') as fileWrite:
      fileWrite.write(file2)
UPLOAD_FOLDER is the path to my directory.
Could you suggest a workaround to avoid saving it to a temporary file on my system and still be able to process it.

Comment: Saving as a temporary file is not too bad - as far as I know it not gets written to the hard disk immediately. You could also use a `tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile` instead - see https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html Also, you could use `io.BytesIo` as a buffer ( https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html ). As a general advice -1. make it work 2. make it right 3. make it fast :-)